# Python - Parsing and converting string into timestamp

Tags: regex, python-2.7, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

I have string in next format: **2017-02-14T09:51:46.000-0600**

What is the best approach to parse and convert string into timestamp?
  I have options to use regular expression or to write my own function for parsing, but are there any builtin methods which can help me?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the search functionality. For what it's worth, my go-to solution is `dateutil.parser.parse('2017-02-14T09:51:46.000-0600').timestamp()` (totally untested, so no guarantee). But I use `dateutil.parser.parse` mostly because I am lazy, and I'd expect there are better ways to parse this specific string.

Comment: I do not see a problem with this question. Answer to it is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First part would be creating datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2017-02-14T09:51:46.000-0600"
# I'm using date_string[:-9] to skip ".000-0600"
format_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
```

After which format date is:

```
print(format_date)
2017-02-14 09:51:46
```

And timestamp is:

```
print(format_date.timestamp())
1487062306.0
```

Little clarification here, on python [reference page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), you can see definition for `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')` format specifiers I used.

- **%Y**:  Year with century as a decimal number, e.g. 1970, 1988, 2001, 2013
- **%m**:  Month as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g. 01, 02, ..., 12)
- **%d**:  Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g. 01, 02, ..., 31)
- **%H**:  Hour
  (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g 00, 01, ..., 23)
- **%M**:  Minute as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g 00, 01, ..., 59)
- **%S**: Second as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g. 00, 01, ..., 59)
- **%f**: Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left (000000, 000001, ..., 999999)
- **%z**: UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM, empty string if the the object is naive, (empty or +0000, -0400, +1030)

Comment: Doesn't this miss the timezone? From Python 3.2 onwards, you could do `datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-02-14T09:51:46.000-0600", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').timestamp()` if I recall the format string definition correctly. But because I never can remember it correctly, I use `dateutil.parse.parse` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code form where you can parse and convert string in timestamp

```
import time
import datetime
s = "2017-02-14T09:51:46.000-0600"
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
```

In this case the expected output is

> 1322697600.0

Comment: I got the logic of it but i am working on python,think the built in methods above are in JAVA

Comment: Please edit your answer. He is clearly asking for Python, not Java.