# how to convert the following date format in python: '2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000'

Tags: python

How to convert this date format in python:

```
'2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000'
```

I tried but I'm getting the following error:

```
time data '2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I'm getting te data from third-party API.

Comment: Please post your code, the exact error and advise the format that you want

Comment: It's `%Y` for 4-digit years, not `%y`. Check the [strftime-and-strptime-format-codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Parsing and converting string into timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691220/python-parsing-and-converting-string-into-timestamp)

Comment: Could you please ```print(type('2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000'))``` and let me know what the output is

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime
datess='2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000'

format_date = datetime.strptime(datess, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%f')
print(format_date)
```

Output

`datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 3, 5, 21, 56)`

Method 2

```
from datetime import datetime
datess='2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000'

format_date = datetime.strptime(datess, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(format_date)
```

Output

`datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 3, 5, 21, 56, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

Comment: `%z` is probably more appropriate than `+%f` see [strftime-and-strptime-format-codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Sounds like this should be good enough. One note tho, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'. You missed a space between date and time.

Comment: @NickTritsis He didn't miss. There is a `T` there...

Comment: but the format required expects a space, not a T.      does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: @Tomerikoo okay...anyway I am used to working with ```%f``` so I got to know something new, Thanks!

Comment: @NickTritsis I don't understand you. The string is `2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000`. Notice the `T` between the date and the time?

Comment: @NickTritsis I got the required output, edited the answer, please have a look

Comment: `%f` is wrong. It is for Microsecond. Here it is an offset which is `%z`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Check the answer now

Comment: to my understanding, python says that '2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000' is not ok and it demands something like '2020-12-03 05:21:56', no T, no offset .. no?

Comment: Oh .. silly me. T is the indicator that the time part is following. Datetime knows that tho. My bad!

Comment: No, the string is `2020-12-03T05:21:56+0000`. That's the input. The format specified by the OP doesn't match this input. The one suggested in this answer does match

Comment: @GlenVeigas yes it is ok. But to be honest, and I'm sorry if I'm annoying, the first method shouldn't be at all. It's just wrong... Those are not microseconds...

Comment: @Tomerikoo..Haha thats absolutely fine....agree to your word, I got to learn something here